# angular load <style></style> tags instead css files

Tags: angular

When i run `ng serve` angular not load my css files, instead it's load my component scss inside  tags, the problem is when it loaded that way angular compiler also change my classes names on the console and make it harder to development, for example `span.arrow` become `span.arrow[_ngcontent-c1]`.

I know it possible to see my css files normally just like any website..
and i don't want to turn off the View Encapsulation if possible..

I didn't change any default settings, any ideas?

example[image]

need to mention that i'm using scss maybe it's mean something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the only way to avoid [Angular encapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#encapsulation) is to set it to `None` (`ViewEncapsulation.None`) straight into the component.
Other possible [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) strategies would be:

- Native: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`
  Basically old ShadowDom approach.
- ShadowDom: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` [ShadowDom v1](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom)

By using those two have all the styles within your component shadow-root, so they can be *"easily debugged"* (as you said).